# Google Apps Script / Search for emails by multiple senders

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I have the following script working to get emails from 1x person. How can I add more names to this script and only show emails that are (a) in my inbox AND (b) unread?

```
function to_me_only()
{
  var search = 'to:me from:person1@email.com -is:chats in:inbox -label:meonly';

  try {
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('meonly');
    var threads = GmailApp.search(search);
    var gmailMessages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);

for(var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
  var messagesForThread = gmailMessages[i];
  for(var j=0; j<messagesForThread.length; j++) {
    var messageTo = messagesForThread[j].getTo()
    if(   messageTo.toLowerCase()=='"lastname, firstname" <firstname.lastname@company.com>'
   || messageTo.toLowerCase()=='"firstname.lastname" <firstname.lastname@company.com>'
   || messageTo.toLowerCase()=='firstname lastname <firstname.lastname@company.com>'
   || messageTo.toLowerCase()=='firstname.lastname@company.com'
   || messageTo.toLowerCase()=='<firstname.lastname@company.com>'){
      threads[i].addLabel(label);
    }
  }
}


 } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error');
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use the `OR` operator to match multiple terms.

`label:unread to:me from: person1@email.com OR from: person2@email.com in:inbox`

Keep in mind that gmail by default uses the `AND` operator, so `OR` has to be explicitly defined.

**References:**

[Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)